# How can I check if a role has "grant references" on a given table?

Tags: oracle

I've got a table (MySchema.MyTable) that I want to grant select and references to for a certain role (MyRole).

So, when logged on as "sys as sysdba", I executed the following:

```
grant select, references on MySchema.MyTable to MyRole;
```

I can see my grant permission when I execute:

```
select * from role_tab_privs where role = 'MYROLE'
```

However, that doesn't seem to show my REFERENCES privilege. What do I need to query to see that?

Comment: Part of the reason I'm asking is that the select grant seems to be working but the references grant doesn't, so I'm trying to verify that I've actually got the privilege.

Comment: `select * from dictionary where upper(Comments) like  '%GRANT%'` may point you in the right direction.  perhaps even sys view `ALL_COL_PRIVS_RECD` is what you're looking for.  Dictionary is a godsend in researching available system and meta data

Answer (score 0):

If using oracle 10g to 19c,
ORACLE disallows GRANT of REFERENCES privileges to a role.